# Always open browsers with fixed size

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Every time I open Chrome I would like it to be 900 × 800 in size and stay this size.

How do I do this? Also, I'd be interested to know how this can be done in Safari, Internet Explorer, or Firefox.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to test a layout, you're probably better of using the device metrics overrides.

Comment: In Firefox you can use command line options for height and width, e.g. "firefox -height 900 -width 800"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser resize page [like this one](http://resizemybrowser.com/) to make your browser window the size you desire (you will need to `create a new preset`). I believe that the Chrome window opens at the same dimensions as it was last closed. For example, if you close Chrome when the window measures 900*800, then re-opening Chrome should make the window appear at this size.

I'm not aware, however, of a way of stopping the browser window from being resized by dragging the corners/clicking the maximise button.

**EDIT:**

It seems you will have to manually resize your browser so that the `current inner/outer` displays 900x800. Opening a preset does not give you a regular Chrome window.